# Can you order beers by strength of flavour?

Tags: flavor

I imagine the might would look something like:

```
Pale Lager    
Generic lager.
Pilsner    
Pale Ale (Which style?)    
Imperial Pale Ale    
Stout
```

Of course, I'm not a full on beer aficionado, I don't know all the styles.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have trouble with this because of different dimensions of flavor.  Beer has a very complex flavor and different recipes are different.  One can order beers (if specific enough to include a brand) along any dimension of flavor, but I am not sure that you can order them consistently along all dimensions.

Here are dimensions I would think of:

1. Malty/caramel
2. Hop-forward
3. Bitter (Hops)
4. Yeasty

It isn't clear to me how one rates strength of flavor between an IPA and a porter for example.  So I think the answer here is a simple "no, you can't."